# Multivariate Box Muller

Tags: sampling, monte-carlo

i am reading "machine learning - a probabilistic perspective" by Kevin Murphy - who states the following in the chapter on monte carlo inference. i understand that cov[y] = $\Sigma$, but i do not see why this implies that $y=Lx+\mu$, and why this is equal to multivariate Gaussian sampling. Any hints much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You basically reverse the logic. He plugged $y=Lx+\mu$ into covariance formula, and showed that if you do it then you'll get the given covariance matrix $\Sigma$. This means that sampling $x$ from independent standard normals will give you the required covariance matrix.

Comment: Thanks. And $\mu$ drops out because it is a linear shift and does not affect the covariance?

Comment: @Wouter, yes, just like in a univariate case: $cov[ax+b]=a^2 cov[x]$